# $.each instead of for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to append li five times in body using each function. But it is not working. It should append five li in body
Note: It is just a sample code

```
$(function(){
    var lgt= 5;
    $.each(lgt,function(i){ 
        $('body').append('<li>'+i+'</li>')
    })
})
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Whats wrong with a for loop?

Comment: `<li>` can't be the child of `<body>`. You need either `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: you can use array to define lgt

Comment: This is not what $.each has been designed for. $.each is working on "collections", i.e. lists of objects like jQuery objects, arrays etc. A number is not a list of objects ...

Comment: This is not the purpose of $.each(), use a for loop or while one

Comment: what made you convinced passing an integer to `$.each` would work?

Comment: your code will loop over the properties of an integer. I won't loop 5 times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is ***Why not use a `for` loop*** ?

If you still need to go this way you can use

```
$(function(){
    var lgt= 5;
    $.each(new Array(lgt),function(i){ 
        $('body').append('<li>'+i+'</li>')
    });
});
```

but as others have mentioned you cannot add `li` elements directly to the `body`..

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` expects an array as first parameter, not a number.

You could use `var lgt = new Array(5)` instead of `var lgt = 5`.

Comment: that's a comment on why it doesn't work but not a solution to the problem as such

Comment: The solution should be easy to get from here, or the questioner could ask for more advice if it is not clear. But I will add the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  [jQuery $.each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

I dont think what you are trying to do is valid.

It needs a collection to loop through, you are just passing it a single integer